How to solve the problem of split pdf with DynamicPDF\Api\Pdf?
I have set up a pdf split process using the DynamicPDF\Api\Pdf package according to their documentation and everything was going well. Recently I imported a 36 page pdf and I am facing this error:

An error occurred while adding the log: Unable to split file : 500,
{"id":"663f0305-7d83-4d51-b5c7-bf7612d60201","message":"The Position
must be within the length of the Stream: 6430350 (Parameter
'value')\nActual value was 6455296."}

My code :
<?php

namespace App\Services\dpdf;

use DynamicPDF\Api\Pdf;
use DynamicPDF\Api\PdfResource;

class SplitPdf{

    public static function Run(string $path, $parentPath, string $output_path, $startPage, $pageCount = 1)
    {
        $pdf = new Pdf();
        $pdf->ApiKey = config('pdf.dpdf-api-key');

        $pdfInput = $pdf->AddPdf(new PdfResource($path));
        $pdfInput->StartPage = $startPage;
        $pdfInput->PageCount = $pageCount;

        $response = $pdf->Process();

        if($response->IsSuccessful)
        {
            $storagePath = storage_path('app/temp/'. $parentPath);
            if (!file_exists($storagePath)) {
                mkdir($storagePath, 0755, true);
            }

            $outputPath = $storagePath . '/' . $output_path;

            if (file_put_contents($outputPath, $response->Content) === false) {
                //dd('nok');
                $errorMessage = error_get_last()['message'] ?? 'Erreur inconnue lors de l\'écriture du fichier.';
                throw new \Exception("Impossible d'écrire le fichier : $outputPath. Erreur : $errorMessage");
            }

            file_put_contents($parentPath. '/' .$output_path, $response->Content);
        } else {
            throw new \Exception("Impossible de spliter le fichier : $response->StatusCode, $response->ErrorJson");
        }
    }
}

I tried searching the documentation but couldn't find any leads.

Can you try opening the PDF with a tool such as Acrobat Pro, and see if it detects any errors? Objects in a PDF can have streams, and the object's dictionary can/should have a /Length key for the stream, so it is possible this is off. It could also be the PDF's cross-ref table not being correct, too.

Thank you for your reply. What should I do in this case? Or would it mean that my file is corrupted?

Yeah, this is just a check to see if it is corrupted or not. If another tool says it is corrupted, that'd be up to what you want to do. Personally I'd just log it as an error and move and, it probably isn't worth trying to solve unless it happens often. If it does happen often, I'd then lean on trying to find out why corrupted PDFs are generated in the first place, rather then solving them with my code. For web-based system, you can sometimes open the PDF in a text editor and find HTML (not the normal XML) at the beginning/end of the file, and that's easily solvable by the developers

Very well noted, thank you. I will therefore explore this lead.
